# Pandas - Check adjacent column for value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that tracks the status of an issue. From 'Open', 'In Progress' to 'Closed' like such:

```
        T1          T2           T3     T4      T5 
1      Open        In Progress Closed
2      In Progress Closed
3      Open        In Progress Open    Closed
4      Open        In Progress Closed  Open   Closed
5      Open        In Progress Closed
```

Basically I want to find all issues that get reopened. This can be noted by any row that has a `Closed`value that then has a followup transition. For example, index `4` has a closed value in `T3` but then `T4` contains something to indicate it has been reopened.

The output would be:

```
        T1          T2           T3     T4      T5       Reopened
1      Open        In Progress Closed                       0
2      In Progress Closed                                   0  
3      Open        In Progress Open    Closed               0
4      Open        In Progress Closed  Open   Closed        1
5      Open        In Progress Closed                       0
```

In the real df, the columns range from T1 to T25 and has 50k rows.

So basically I need to check each column, find if closed exists and then check the next column to see if it is not empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think need:

```
df['Reopened'] = ((df == 'Open') & ((df.shift(axis=1)) == 'Closed')).any(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
            T1           T2      T3      T4      T5  Reopened
1         Open  In Progress  Closed     NaN     NaN         0
2  In Progress       Closed     NaN     NaN     NaN         0
3         Open  In Progress    Open  Closed     NaN         0
4         Open  In Progress  Closed    Open  Closed         1
5         Open  In Progress  Closed     NaN     NaN         0
```

**Detail**:

Check `Open` value per `df`:

```
print ((df == 'Open'))
      T1     T2     T3     T4     T5
1   True  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3   True  False   True  False  False
4   True  False  False   True  False
5   True  False  False  False  False
```

With shifted DataFrame check `Closed`:

```
print (df.shift(axis=1))
    T1           T2           T3      T4      T5
1  NaN         Open  In Progress  Closed     NaN
2  NaN  In Progress       Closed     NaN     NaN
3  NaN         Open  In Progress    Open  Closed
4  NaN         Open  In Progress  Closed    Open
5  NaN         Open  In Progress  Closed     NaN

print ((df.shift(axis=1)) == 'Closed')
      T1     T2     T3     T4     T5
1  False  False  False   True  False
2  False  False   True  False  False
3  False  False  False  False   True
4  False  False  False   True  False
5  False  False  False   True  False
```

Then chain together by `&` to `AND` and get at least one `True` per rows by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (((df == 'Open') & ((df.shift(axis=1)) == 'Closed')))
      T1     T2     T3     T4     T5
1  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False   True  False
5  False  False  False  False  False

print (((df == 'Open') & ((df.shift(axis=1)) == 'Closed')).any(axis=1))
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

And last convert boolean mask to integers by `astype` and assign to new column:

```
df['Reopened'] = ((df == 'Open') & ((df.shift(axis=1)) == 'Closed')).any(axis=1).astype(int)
print (df)
            T1           T2      T3      T4      T5  Reopened
1         Open  In Progress  Closed     NaN     NaN         0
2  In Progress       Closed     NaN     NaN     NaN         0
3         Open  In Progress    Open  Closed     NaN         0
4         Open  In Progress  Closed    Open  Closed         1
5         Open  In Progress  Closed     NaN     NaN         0
```

Comment: @AntonvBR - Why think `In Progress Closed Open  In Progress Closed` shoud not work?  because Open is matched with first Closed. I understand question need check Open and previous Close (if understand it well, sure ;))